# Remove WhatsApp images from OneDrive Photo library

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, onedrive

I'm trying to remove WhatsApp clutter from my private photos folder on OneDrive. I'm using OneDrive on Android and it seems it is being used as the backup target for WhatsApp and Viber.

I really need a suggestion on how to remove the whole WhatsApp lot from the OneDrive and stop syncing new ones.

If there is an API and a WhatsApp tag of some sort, I'm open to creating a shared script on github.

Comment: Can OneDrive stop syncing certain folders? WhatsApp images are located in `/sdcard/Media/WhatsApp Images`

Comment: I'm trying to remove all Whatsapp Images already synced to OneDrive.